# VS2010 Intellisense: make it autocomplete every word?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

hello
i'm using VS to write JavaScript lately. before that i was using notepad++.
the auto-completion in np++ deals with every word in the current document.
 but the one in VS only deals with variables and functions and so.
what i'm looking for is every word completion. meaning that if i write
`div.id ="anotherDiv";`
and then later write
`document.getElementById("ano....` i get a suggestion with every matching word ..
is there a way to make VS do that ?

Comment: Pretty sure VS2010's intellisense is fully enabled out of the box. Might want to look into a 3rd party plugin like Resharper. They may offer the extra functionality you're looking for.

Comment: thank you  i'm gonna try it out !